# DataTables column width: small values not working

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to set the column width of my DataTables column to a small value (like `10px`).

According to [the docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width), I should be able to use:

```
$('#mytable').dataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [
      { "width": "10px", "targets": 0 }
    ]
} );
```

This seems to work for larger values (like `100px`) but not for the smaller ones I'm trying to use.

My column header and cells in that column just contain `&nbsp;` so these shouldn't be defining the width.
I removed the sorting possibilities from the header so that's not eating up space either (`"orderable": false`).

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/snoodaard/ak11heu4/

I also tried to set the width explicitly using `<th width="5px">&nbsp;</th>`.

Any pointers on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can hide the column if there is no data in it. Column width is also affected by padding, you would need to add CSS rules to overcome that.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com: the data in the table is populated by different users categorized in groups. I'm trying to add a column in which the cells would get a certain CSS class showing a certain color or background-image. Basically this narrow column (just showing the color) would indicate which group of users added the particular content/row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use the following code to remove padding and content for the last column and color all cells in certain color.

**JavaScript**

```
$('#mytable').dataTable({
    "order": [],
    "paging": false,
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "columnDefs": [{
        "className": "tag",
        "orderable": false,
        "width": "2px",
        "targets": 2
    }]
});
```

**CSS**

```
table.dataTable thead tr th.tag,
table.dataTable tbody tr td.tag {
    padding:0;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

table.dataTable tbody tr td.tag,
table.dataTable tbody tr td.tag {
    background-color:red;
}
```

You can use [`createdRow`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) callback to set a class for a row based on the row data. Then you would be able to color each row differently based on that data.

> **DEMO**

See [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ak11heu4/2/) for code and demonstration.